# bootstrap modal+ajax+jquery+validation+.net core 2.0

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a simple movie database kind of an app for learning bootstrap and mvc. I used adminlte template in .net core 2.0. everything is working fine with only mvc. But later I wish to learn more so I started to use ajax and jquery to send and receive data. For create/edit/ I used the bootstrap modal. Here I have the main problem. I can validate from client side. But I am unable to display error message during server side validation.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/adminlte/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" />
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Google Font -->
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">*@

    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SlimScroll -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="~/lib/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="~/lib/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <!-- Site wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- Top Menubar -->
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("TopMenubar")

        <!-- Left side column. contains the sidebar -->
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Sidebar")

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section class="content-header">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("ContentHeader")
                <br />
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Alert")
            </section>

            <section class="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Footer")

    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script>

    </script>
    @*<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.sidebar-menu').tree()
            })
        </script>*@
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MovieDb.Models.CategoryType

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Category Type";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="~/lib/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/categoryType.js"></script>


<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createNewEmergencyType"
                onclick="clearTextBox();"><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add New Category</i></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-body table-responsive">
        <table id="DgCategoryType" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" role="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="createNewCategoryType" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="Add New Category" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">

             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                     &times;
                 </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Category</h4>
             </div>

             <div class="modal-body">
                 <form id="createCTForm">
                     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                         <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                         <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>

                 </form>
             </div>

             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-width" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Add();">
                     Add
                 </button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-fixed-width" data-dismiss="modal">
                     Close
                 </button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

categoryType.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
loadData();
});

function loadData(){
    $("#DgCategoryType").DataTable(

        {           
            "filter": true,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "ajax":
            {
                "url":"/CategoryTypes/LoadData",
                "type":"GET",
                "dataType":"JSON"
            },
            "columns":[
                {"data":"Name"},
                {   "data":"Id",
                    "render":function(data){
                        return "<a class='popup' href='/CategoryTypes/Edit/"+data+"'>Edit</a> | <a class='popup' href='/CategoryTypes/Delete/"+data+"'>Delete</a>";
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columnDefs":
            [
                {
                    "targets": [1],
                    "searchable": false
                },
                {"width":"10%","targets":[1]}
            ]
        }
    );
}

function Add(){

    /*var frm=document.getElementById("createCTForm");
    var data=toJSONString(frm);*/

    var data=$("#createCTForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"CategoryTypes/Create",
        data:data,
        success:function(result){
            if(result.success)
            {
                $("#createNewCategoryType").modal("hide");
            }
        },
    });
}

function clearTextBox(){
    $("#Name").val("");
}
```

Model: CategoryType.cs

```
public class CategoryType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Category name required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryTypesController.cs

```
public class CategoryTypesController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CategoryTypesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
                _context.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        // GET: CategoryTypes
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            AddPageHeader("Category Types");
            return View(new CategoryType());
        }

        //GET JSON data for loading the datatable
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoadData()
        {
            var data = await _context.CategoryTypes.ToListAsync();
            return Json(new { data } );
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] CategoryType categoryType)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(CategoryType);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Json(new { success=true });
            }
                return Json(new { success=false });
        }
    }
```

when I run the above code it will add the new category to database however if I didn't enter the name in modal input box then controller will give the error but validation message will not appear.

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recenly faced the same problem. To solve it, I took the matter into my own hands, and created a mini-library (if you can call it that) to validate the inputs.
Please get the code from [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VladBullet/yxv3L5jn/110/).
You can find a working example in the same link.

Note: As of right now it has checks for : required, regex, range, equals.
You can add more checks by yourself, or comment about it, if you need help and I will try my best to provide aid.

How it works:

1.Create a js file in your project and paste the js (minimum code is reprezented by region CustomValidationScript) from the fiddle link. Include this file in your _layout.cshtml.

2.Setup some rules:

```
    var validationRules = [{ 
        ruleName: "elementId1ShoudBeRequired", // make sure this 
        name will be unique within your rules 
        ruleForElementId: "#elementId1",
        check: "required",
        comparerValue: true,
        message: "This input is required! Please make sure to input a value!"
    },
    {
        ruleName: "elementId3ShouldBePhoneNr",
        ruleForElementId: "#elementId2",
        check: "regex",
        comparerValue: /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/,
        message: "Please provide a valid phone number!"
    },
    {
        ruleName: "elementId4_ShouldBeEqualWith_5",
        ruleForElementId: "#elementId2",
        check: "equals",
        comparerValue: 5,
        message: "This input should be 5!"
    }
    ];
    var rangeRules = [{
        ruleName: "elementId2ShoudBeInRange",
        ruleForElementId: "#elementId2",
        check: "range",
        comparerValue: [1, 8],
        message: "Please provide a value between 1 and 8 !"
    }];
```

3. In your js file / script initialize the validator outside of $(document).ready() function:

   ```
    var validator = new CustomValidation(validationRules);
    // you can pass the validation rules in the initialization, or send a empty array if you wish to add the rules later
    // var validator = new CustomValidation([]);
   ```
4. *(optional step)* Add or remove more validation rules:

   ```
    // Add rules
    // you can add them by passing an array of rules
    validator.addcustomValidationRules(rangeRules);
    // or by passing one rule
    validator.addcustomValidationRule(
        {
            ruleName: addRule.ruleName,
            ruleForElementId: addRule.ruleForElementId,
            check: addRule.check,
            comparerValue: addRule.comparerValue,
            message: addRule.message
        }
    );
    // if the rule(s) already exist(s), an error will be thrown

    // Remove rules
    // you can also remove some rules by ruleName, or sending an array of rules
    // for example we can remove rangeRules entirely like : 
    validator.removeCustomValidationRules(rangeRules);
    // or we can remove individual rules by name like so: 
    validator.removeCustomValidationRule("elementId2ShoudBeInRange");
   ```
5. Validate the inputs:

   `var result = validator.validate(validator);  // will return an object like this:{ formIsvalid : true / false, validationResults: [ {elementId: elementId,message: message}] }`

   HTML page example:

   ```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Input for elementId1 </label>
        <input id="elementId1" class="validate" />
        <span class="error_span col-md-12"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Input for elementId2 </label>
        <input id="elementId2" class="validate" />
        <span class="error_span"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="save">Save</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // you can validate the input inside listeners or inside whatever pieces of code

    // example onClick
    $("#save").on("click", function() {
        // the validation happerns here
        var result = validator.validate(validator);
        if (result.formIsValid) {
            // your code ...  
            // can be ajax call to send the form to the server
        }
        else {
            // clear error_spans that might have been fixed between clicks
            updateUi(result.validationResults, "form-group", "error_span");
        }
    });

    // example onKeyUp
    $(".validate").on("keyup", function() {
        var result = validator.validate(validator);
        updateUi(result.validationResults, "form-group", "error_span");
    });

    </script>
   ```

Note : updateUi (can also be found in the JsFiddle) is a custom function that updates the error spans to show / hide.

That's it!

I tested it with ajax calls, select2, bootstrap 4 and it works.

Feel free to comment if you find something that can be improved. (I'm not a js wizzard, so mistakes could be found.)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why validation didn't work in above method. I have to use jquery-unobtrusive-ajax. You can refer it here https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/

Validate Pop Up Modal using Ajax.Beginform tutorial is here
https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp.net/validate-pop-up-modal-using-ajaxbeginform-in-c-mvc/52

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by linking the **jquery-validate** and the **jquery-validation-unobtrusive** scripts with the view that you're calling through the modal.

You need that because any view acting as a partial view does not have access to scripts or script tags on the layout view.